# How to solve the problem "error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181" when using 'slint' to build app?

Tags: qt, rust

I try to build slint desktop app on https://slint.dev/releases/1.0.2/docs/tutorial/rust/getting_started.

but when i input `cargo build`  , this is the result:

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
  |
  = note: "E:\\Softwares\\Visual Studio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "C:\\Users\\lxl11\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc3x0qh1\\symbols.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1094040omrcb5nmi.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.14pxj7ruhb20ouzb.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.16dr13ju3b3hu0tj.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1804c1xy3o5k0vjq.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.19il9lbno6oiy0cl.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1ellz9vglpaxdla7.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1i6ajtcuc1fvpnwb.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1r6jdy7wq27mngeu.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1vqnbls2hf387nxz.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1yyfco1pjlwva94r.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1zvl5ar94817tnbn.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.1zz8xrqd8fbun5ky.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.214xogh9qvi8wlpt.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.27z4c5qmfcbvkz0d.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.2cnrquoa610lwrjt.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.2kvo8bj8f2f07zad.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.2kxfa167h77i91ik.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.2lb0ifpaajt8nefr.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.2o0ld397vsbqtr65.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.2pobh1l8qa803iin.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.2x6ym97p0c5ks7rr.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.31xuxbruvv89qxwr.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.32xwudil3gawssjx.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.356w9h9wdy3p8k0r.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3680k01ess2l2u03.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.37ti2jzy9jpipglb.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3aog1uh2lf661bxg.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3htwgnapwkz11sub.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3m5au6sqxh9ys8r1.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3oakaum162r5jbq6.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3rm6sixp8rcyq9kv.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3xxqef85w6bhwmpn.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3zg3n5dy49956n82.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.3zveu2htubxq6pr4.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.405ddsxvbij52p3o.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.45s9gbzpf1zqsja7.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.4azkg56wujr43cvt.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.4h34c5b5noxpf8s4.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.4ouoa8kiem27p2b6.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.4pf9lw14062rggrb.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.4rv93int2ig2zipv.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.5571dt0ablwuof1i.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.59g7siu2cu6xo1dr.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.59zsgta5x6ytfdmn.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.5g4h39mxm7l2lcgp.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.5v8zs83dz6zw5ef.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.7ozpqlg2uymgcye.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.eb4gaa6dk6qpv04.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.eg6oeozjnb1pob9.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.fun8zp39lnd9fth.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.hi1dd9gkes428p7.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.m9drsw575n33oiu.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.mk4stha8dgkmaya.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.w0r8nu3hobvceo1.rcgu.o" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.4txopy2ub3zcmpsz.rcgu.o" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Softwares\\Visual Studio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\atlmfc\\lib\\x64" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\build\\i-slint-backend-qt-231cbd5dd5e3b2c3\\out" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Softwares\\Visual Studio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\atlmfc\\lib\\x64" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\build\\qttypes-4bd5fb9e0dcbf98a\\out" "/LIBPATH:E:/Environments/Anaconda/Library/lib" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Environments\\Cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\windows_x86_64_msvc-0.42.2\\lib" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libslint-67a095baa28c70f9.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libi_slint_backend_selector-e58097ec1cbc5b8e.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libi_slint_backend_winit-45ee9059775a0e40.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libglutin_winit-0afd8b6d16fc70e8.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libglutin-ebf6544809a53dab.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libglutin_wgl_sys-1f73c3d3b2c6ce54.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibloading-e4450367e2b793db.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libglutin_egl_sys-cdc0779092ca42bd.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libi_slint_renderer_femtovg-f5becc538da13f35.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libdwrote-b5939f9db076831d.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwio-98775a0eaf14fc1a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibc-4b2728a32b4c2fd3.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblazy_static-76811ada8a384ec4.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde-2a1384c56a0bc3d1.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfontdb-c830b92d2b3bca4e.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmemmap2-d80cdbd3c9af5a62.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfemtovg-d4e1ec7646fda9b2.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libglow-ef80448cec41af65.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libimgref-0f0660c650c7948b.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libouroboros-0f7102a847a6e397.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libaliasable-6f59c0e432f953e8.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_bidi-8ca03ebde944ff9a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\librustybuzz-1dc59e4815f1623c.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_bidi_mirroring-0ff68a1230328ea4.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_ccc-cdcee986735ddc68.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_general_category-7ceb9b0b6b7fd9dd.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsmallvec-b365af88dd4f6262.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libttf_parser-7850c8ee29455cc5.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblru-34e1814aeb73ebaa.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgenerational_arena-9c264ecc9b279f77.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfnv-a03929684059b749.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinit-eeea4fa9c26b5cfd.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwindows_sys-55d295c8afb0db0c.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libraw_window_handle-c22204d6ced1aa8d.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcopypasta-53117fc8133d1731.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libclipboard_win-8627e8b5f508c013.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblazy_bytes_cast-a62e5ead2e207825.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinapi-659f0a1f4354bb8e.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libi_slint_backend_qt-5d1a9901628fbbb2.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libqttypes-981f90ab2ccb2a49.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcpp-1e6dc015a3b61ba4.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libi_slint_core-a4b350a2f1a84efa.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpin_weak-f1de919caa616e77.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libslab-7f1003a4ab39fe13.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libinstant-5d61f8e2192c23dc.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libimage-7577459ac372440a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcolor_quant-d5f73d2806991ed2.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbyteorder-59924e8a902cddd1.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libnum_rational-6119ac2e1a45c3bc.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libnum_integer-fc5421992d7a1dfc.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libjpeg_decoder-3cddea634e80bdb8.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libclru-6a33e9a993035313.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblyon_extra-a95d110815e5646a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblyon_algorithms-a406e48e5750d03d.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libscopeguard-2f60b7f0eb7b7422.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libscoped_tls_hkt-518192f1b8e2be00.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libi_slint_common-cc3e8036c8bff95c.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libstrum-908d652d89f9b25a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_script-dd45dcf0400d855a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_linebreak-942ded24667f3a3e.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libinteger_sqrt-322c25d65e01c494.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpin_project-3ec44bd2612ce1d4.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libonce_cell-16e885091df34dc9.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_segmentation-25ff9ea4eabe366c.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\librgb-7922bd5d138fb15c.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libresvg-8392c7b45dabb199.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libusvg-75059fd72330d5ee.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbase64-85155001319a5e45.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libxmlwriter-e2e7ee3587b0f223.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libusvg_parser-07e16b9c89e2615f.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libdata_url-4ffea875d3e14b46.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libimagesize-45346cec51daa7a3.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libusvg_tree-63c1045e3246ebcb.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\librctree-b0aa857c5c6cdb86.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\librosvgtree-f0e819f7e5b5d9fb.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsvgtypes-ea9ff4ed10632d41.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libkurbo-5b0f74d81990202e.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsimplecss-2b8ad4c78389cafd.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsiphasher-b5bb6efe258b5d69.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libroxmltree-780f4fd6f1de4415.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libxmlparser-061e84ada4af0eb2.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtiny_skia-9fba386baac2f018.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpng-1a637b627002a4f8.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libflate2-bf26262a4d0e79aa.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libminiz_oxide-9bb49f44a009be6f.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfdeflate-87fddebac475db23.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsimd_adler32-99d618137fe1fdd4.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcrc32fast-78cb9ea565c30f1a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbitflags-238d36ea99b67de1.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcfg_if-5ddb140102fcb6a2.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblog-dfecb4bfe1b79fcd.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtiny_skia_path-3ec7ed68948bd61f.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbytemuck-2392be8df9ed7041.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libstrict_num-0d21c818b7d2398d.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfloat_cmp-f6b8568b9cd9839b.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libarrayref-05ad163a3f69039e.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblyon_path-7179e7d939a7b234.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblyon_geom-6d2c2bd6db7db4a2.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libarrayvec-2dae57c1de885356.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libvtable-9809376d4eba9e72.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libstable_deref_trait-7bc0cf3f5317488c.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libatomic_polyfill-4020559586acbba9.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libconst_field_offset-1fd7f9b1a8bc9d4a.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfield_offset-efec592115314c21.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmemoffset-2bfda58f6c387739.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libeuclid-fd9cb33137c5ab8d.rlib" "E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\libnum_traits-954ceb24f4f9fd43.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-391022a4250a8b9a.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-3069c74fd845ecc2.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-cae8325b8f11cb55.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd_detect-6ecbb4a24be3ec33.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-7cef55517a70b408.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-d1e72b1788c7e8f6.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libadler-65d80753bac4b1a6.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-932a6231bea08890.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-04ed514427316340.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-9b75e26b1d0a074f.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-95c2795d82b7b742.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-1bf02ac2d8cdb80a.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-117dfa1fe8688bcf.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-9ac5797c0b4842d0.rlib" "E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-ad271357e078d260.rlib" "opengl32.lib" "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" "windows.lib" "advapi32.lib" "cfgmgr32.lib" "d2d1.lib" "dwrite.lib" "dxgi.lib" "gdi32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "msimg32.lib" "ole32.lib" "opengl32.lib" "shell32.lib" "shlwapi.lib" "user32.lib" "windowscodecs.lib" "winspool.lib" "msvcrtd.lib" "Qt5Cored.lib" "Qt5Guid.lib" "Qt5Widgetsd.lib" "kernel32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "userenv.lib" "kernel32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "bcrypt.lib" "ntdll.lib" "msvcrt.lib" "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "/OUT:E:\\Data\\rust\\memory\\target\\debug\\deps\\memory.exe" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/NATVIS:E:\\Environments\\Rust\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libstd.natvis"
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Qt5Cored.lib'


error: could not compile `memory` (bin "memory") due to previous error
```

Comment: You need to install the Qt5 development libraries.

Answer (score 1):

install the Qt5 library.
and `cargo clean`, `cargo build`

the `cargo clean` is necessary!